# Radio Button List validation

Tags: asp.net, validation

I want to validate `Status` three ways:

1. `Status` is a required field: a user must select one status.
2. If user selects `Accept`, then:

   - Qty Rejected should be Disabled
   - Comments are not compulsory. The user may leave a comment or not.
3. If user select `Reject`, then:

   - The user must put valid range of `Qty Rejected`, from 1 to 1000 with no non-numeric characters.
   - Must place a Comment.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: If you can provide some code that you tried with, we can help you find any mistakes you may have done.

Comment: You really need to provide more information about what you've tried, what code is attempting to handle this case already, and _what problems you're running into when implementing this_. Note that S.O. is not a place where you can ask someone to simply implement this for you, but we can help you if you run into a _specific_ problem.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript would be your best route for this. An easier route would also be to use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

Always recheck the information passed to you server side again. I know it seems redundant, but it's for your safety and it provides a better user experience.

Comment: [So this web page](http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/marketo/) is an example of [this jQuery form validator plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose to use javascript/jQuery for all the validations. But you can also use Data Annotations, `[Required]`. 
So, using your numbers above:

1) you can use the Data Annotation or JS/jQuery.

2) You can will have to use Data Annotations and/or JS/jQuery. The Data Annotation can handle making sure the input is a number and between 1 and 1000. You will have to use JS/jQuery to check if the Accept/Reject radio button was selected, or disable the Qty Rejected input based on the radio button selection.

3) The comments section can be declared required using JS/jQuery based on the radio button as well.

Info/examples on javascript validation: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Do i have option to do all this validation "Validation " available in ASP validation Toolbox??

Comment: You won't be able to handle all the validation in your backend code because you are wanting to make some of the validations conditional (like your scenario in number 2).